# json php return nothing with ajax

Tags: php, html, json

hi guys i wrote this simple test for my php code and it's not working !!!
I want to get err value but it's not working

2.php

```
    $error="abc";
    $er=json_encode($error);
    return $er;
```

my html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>my btn</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "2.php", 
                success: function(result){
                    var er=JSON.parse(result);
                    $("res").html(er);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="res"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for AJAX to work, you must echo your return from the PHP file:

```
$error="abc";
$er=json_encode($error);
echo $er;
```

What many fail to realize is that an HTTP request is made and when you use `return` you're only returning the function's output to the local script, not to the HTTP response.

Comment: i got this error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input "

Comment: I cannot duplicate the error. What does `$error` actually contain?

Comment: the browser send this : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Add `dataType: "JSON"` to the parameters of your AJAX request.

Comment: Let's remove JSON from the equation - comment out the line that creates the JSON and just `echo $error;` In the AJAX request change the data type, `dataType: "text"` run that and see what happens.